# How to open new screen on ReactJS on Web

Tags: reactjs, web, react-navigation

How to open InvokeScreen Thank you very much.

This is App.js

```
import React from "react";
import { Grid } from "semantic-ui-react";
import QueryAllCars from "./components/queryAllCars";

const App = () => {
return (
<div>
 <QueryAllCars/>
</div>
);
};

export default App;
```

This is QueryAllCars.js

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

const QueryAllCars = () => {
return (
<div>
 <Button onClick={moveToInvokeScreen}>Move to InvokeScreen</Button>
</div>
);
};

const moveToInvokeScreen = () => {
   //???????What code is here??? 
}
export default QueryAllCars;
```

This is InvokeScreen file

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";
import { Button } from "semantic-ui-react";

const InvokeScreen = () => {
return (
  <div>
    Invoke Screen
  </div>
);
};
export default InvokeScreen;
```

What code is here???

```
const moveToInvokeScreen = () => {
 //???????What code is here??? 
}
```

Please help me. How to open InvokeScreen Thank you very much.

Comment: What you are probably looking for is called "routing". React doesn't come with a routing framework on its own, but you can use the npm package `react-router`. Here are the docs: https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/guides/quick-start